# Please review my Promtail configuration file

Tags: grafana, grafana-alerts, grafana-loki, promtail

Please review my Promtail configuration file. I am unclear on the purpose of `positions.yaml` and how the client URL `http://localhost:3100/loki/api/v1/push` works. Additionally, what is the significance of the path `/loki/api/v1/push` in the client section of the config?

```yaml
server:
  http_listen_port: 9080
  grpc_listen_port: 0

positions:
  filename: /tmp/positions.yaml

clients:
  - url: http://localhost:3100/loki/api/v1/push

scrape_configs:
- job_name: system
  static_configs:
  - targets:
      - localhost
    labels:
      job: varlogs
      __path__: E:/logs/my.logs
```